# Detect when DOM is unloaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to detect when a DOM has been unloaded (destroyed/removed/GCed etc.)?

I have a global hub where I subscribe to a bunch of listeners (using reactive subject). I need to detect when a relevant DOM has been destroyed and unsubscribe listeners that pertain to the now destroyed DOM.

Comment: Did you search for it? What about this? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Mozilla_event_reference/unload

Comment: btw if you want to detect when the user closes the window you can use `window.onbeforeunload`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the load event, there is an unload event. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onunload

Comment: It should be noted that there is a very restricted set of actions you can take from an unload handler and firing an ajax call may not work as the page context may be deleted before the ajax call gets out (this seems to vary by browser).

Answer (score 1):

If you are removing DOM using jQuery you can use the `remove` event:

```
$("#myDiv").on("remove", function () {
    //code here
})
```

Vanilla jQuery does not trigger `remove` event. This behaviour depends on jQuery UI being loaded together with jQuery. Instead of jQuery UI, you can extend the `.remove()` method, https://stackoverflow.com/a/18410194/368691.

Comment: Is this real or did you make it up? I've never seen it, can't find a reference for it, and can't get it to work in an example: http://jsfiddle.net/t2Tbb/

Comment: Oooh okay, never saw that berfore!

Comment: If you update your answer to explain this, and include the jsFiddle, I'd gladly remove my downvote :)