# What is the proper way of binding REMOVE event listener to dynamically created elements in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

My goal is to perform a certain operation each time an element with a certain id or class is deleted from DOM. Prior to this, I've been successfully using a standard syntax for binding click events on dynamically created elements like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.someClass', function(e) {
    alert("Div was clicked");
  });
```

Inspired by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200494/jquery-trigger-event-when-an-element-is-removed-from-the-dom), I tried to do the same thing for REMOVE event listener, and  failed. 
Here is my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wphtjw1o/).

Any hints on how to make this work? And maybe what I am trying to do is fundamentally wrong, and I should come up with some entirely different logic ?

http://jsfiddle.net/wphtjw1o/

Comment: Note, in the linked post it says you need to load _jQuery UI_ as well

Comment: Check this post too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18410050/jquery-remove-method-doesnt-trigger-onremove-event

Answer (score 0):

This is the functionality of Jquery UI script, so you have to include two scripts  Jquery and Jquery UI to make it work.

```js
$(function() {
  $('<div id="DivToBeRemoved">DIV TO BE REMOVED</div>').prependTo('body');
  $("#DivToBeRemoved").on("remove", function () {
        alert("Element was removed");
    });

  $(document).on('click', '#DivToBeRemoved', function(e) {
    alert("Div was clicked");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

   
<button onclick="RemoveDiv();">Click here to remove div above</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function RemoveDiv() {
    var d = $("#DivToBeRemoved");
    d.remove();
  }

</script>
```

Comment: And where is a sample of OP's code showing this actually works?

Comment: I really tried to include the UI library as well, and still it doesn't work. So I should really appreciate a working code

Comment: Ihor, thanks for the answer. Yet, I've mentioned that the core detail here is that the elements are DYNAMICALLY added. So your code should work for static elements only.

Comment: Edgar, as you can see, I generate the element with jQuery now, and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If I got you correctly, you trying to write custom event (*`remove` event in your case*).

For calling custom event you don't need any library, you need to `trigger` that event, like so:

```
function RemoveDiv() {
    var d = $("#DivToBeRemoved");

    // d.remove();
    d.trigger('remove'); // <--
}
```

Read more about trigger: [.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

Also check this question here on SO: [Custom events in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/399867/3367974)

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdehghani/wphtjw1o/2/)